# Python returning a list

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm using bs4 and iterated through all of the links on a single page I need. I then stored those links in a list.

Here's my code:

```
def scrape1(self):

    html = self.browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    # add links to list for later use
    urls = []
    for videos in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'watch-now'}):
        links = videos['href']
        urls.append(links)

    return urls

def use(self):

    urls = scrape1()
```

I thought when using return I could use the urls in a different method? I want to be able to use every link I appended to the url list, is their a better way to do this when using classes that I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Since these are the instance methods, you should be using `self` to call them:

```
def use(self):
    urls = self.scrape1()
```

And, you don't have to return from the `scrape1()` method and can set an instance attribute, e.g.:

```
class MyScraper():
    # ...

    def scrape1(self):
        html = self.browser.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

        self.urls = [a['href'] for a in soup.select('a.watch-now')]

    def use(self):
        self.scrape1()

        # use self.urls
        print(self.urls)
```

And, you will be able to use the `urls` this way as well:

```
scraper = MyScraper()
scraper.scrape1()

print(scraper.urls)
```

Comment: It's returning a empty list when using the "use" method how would I correctly define urls in the class instance?

Comment: @listen could it be that there are no `a` elements with `watch-now` class in the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

you could just have the method return the urls into an attribute of the class.

```
self.urls = urls
```

then you could reference that from other methods.

anything with self. are attributes that you can reference across the class. So you could write another method that (without needing to feed it as a parameter for the function) could use self.urls in the function.